# How to translate this line of code from C# to Visual Baisc

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, bing-maps, bing-api

i need some help on one line with translating this code:

Original in C#:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl;

namespace Binding_Bing_Map_Control.Modal
{
public class MapModal
{
    public Location MapLocation { get; set; }
    public string TooltipText { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<MapModal> getMapRecords()
    {
        ObservableCollection<MapModal> MapRecords = new ObservableCollection<MapModal>();
        MapRecords.Add(new MapModal() { MapLocation = new Location(47.610015, -122.188362), TooltipText = "Main St, Bellevue, WA 98004" });
        MapRecords.Add(new MapModal() { MapLocation = new Location(47.603562, -122.329496), TooltipText = "James St, Seattle, wa 98104" });
        MapRecords.Add(new MapModal() { MapLocation = new Location(47.609355, -122.189970), TooltipText = "Main St, Bellevue, WA 98004-6405" });
        MapRecords.Add(new MapModal() { MapLocation = new Location(47.615820, -122.238973), TooltipText = "601 76th Ave, Medina ,WA 98039" });
        return MapRecords;
    }
}
}
```

My translation to VB:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports Microsoft.Maps.MapControl

Namespace Map_Control.Modal

Public Class MapModal

    Public Property Location As WPF.Location
    Public Property TooltipTex As String

    Public Function getMapRecors() As ObservableCollection(Of MapModal)
        Dim MapRecords As New ObservableCollection(Of MapModal)
        MapRecords.Add(New MapModal() {Location = New WPF.Location(47, -122), TooltipTex = "Sample tooltiptext!"})
        Return MapRecords
    End Function

End Class

End Namespace
```

I get error in line:

```
MapRecords.Add(New MapModal() {Location = New WPF.Location(47, -122), TooltipTex = "Sample tooltiptext!"})
```

Error: Value of type Boolean cannot be converted to WindowsApplication1.Map_Control.Modal.MapModal

To clarify what am I doing. I am trying to build wpf application and use bing maps. I am following code from this [link.](http://asimsajjad.blogspot.com/2010/10/binding-bing-map-pushipin.html), but i am not using Silverlight and i am coding in VB.

Comment: +1 for a translation question that is specific, well documented and not simply saying "convert my code for me".

Comment: +1 - same as @Evanlewis - Plus its useful as a question to link other translate questions to

Comment: I think everyone came here expecting another "convert all this code for me" question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
MapRecords.Add(New MapModal() With {.Location = New WPF.Location(47, -122), .TooltipTex = "Sample tooltiptext!"})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
public Location MapLocation { get; set; }
```

This line can't be translated to

```
Public Property Location As WPF.Location
```

I think you're messing with Location class. Notice that there is not such a reference to WPF namespace in the C# version.

Comment: I am using different References. In original the reference points to 'silverlight maps api' where i am using 'wpf maps api'.

Answer (score 1):

The object initialiazer syntax is different in VB.Net - I used [an online translator](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) and got this:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports Microsoft.Maps.MapControl

Namespace Binding_Bing_Map_Control.Modal
    Public Class MapModal

        Public Property Location As Location
        Public Property TooltipTex As String

        Public Shared Function getMapRecords() As ObservableCollection(Of MapModal)
            Dim MapRecords As New ObservableCollection(Of MapModal)()
            MapRecords.Add(New MapModal() With { _
                Key .MapLocation = New Location(47.610015, -122.188362), _
                Key .TooltipText = "Main St, Bellevue, WA 98004" _
            })
            MapRecords.Add(New MapModal() With { _
                Key .MapLocation = New Location(47.603562, -122.329496), _
                Key .TooltipText = "James St, Seattle, wa 98104" _
            })
            MapRecords.Add(New MapModal() With { _
                Key .MapLocation = New Location(47.609355, -122.18997), _
                Key .TooltipText = "Main St, Bellevue, WA 98004-6405" _
            })
            MapRecords.Add(New MapModal() With { _
                Key .MapLocation = New Location(47.61582, -122.238973), _
                Key .TooltipText = "601 76th Ave, Medina ,WA 98039" _
            })
            Return MapRecords
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```